# Process builder: Evaluate lookup field in criteria

Tags: process-builder, automation

In a process I'm building, I'm trying to evaluate if a particular lookup field is changed and proceed to the "action" if so. Simple enough, right?

It appears that there isn't any way to do that sort of field evaluation on a lookup field. Process Builder forces me to drill to the related object. For example, if I want to evaluate the Account.CSM/RM custom lookup field, Process Builder forces me to select Account.CSM/RM.UserId instead. This doesn't accomplish what I'm looking for - I need to evaluate the field on the account, not on the user record.

Am I missing something obvious?

I have some ideas for workaround that involve creating a new text field and workflow rule/field update in addition to the process, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this.  I just did a test in my dev org and it worked fine.  For Owner ID, there are two choices, the field itself (no arrow), or the related object (with an arrow).  Make sure that you are choosing the Owner ID field itself, and not drilling into the Owner object.  See below

[image]

Then you have your conidtion that checks that the ownerID field (on the account) has changed

[image]

> EDIT:

Here is a look at a custom lookup field to the user object.  I still get two options

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ninja. I chose a poor example in an attempt to post a relatable question. My actual use case is a custom lookup field called "CSM/RM" on the account. It doesn't appear that this works with custom lookup fields. I've edited my original post to make the question more clear.

Comment: Hmmmm.  I can't seem to replicate.  I have a custom lookup on account called 'Premium Plus TAM', it's just a custom lookup field to the user object.  It sounds like its similar to your use case.  I get both options the Id field itself, and the option to drill into it.  I added it to my answer.  Are you not getting the two options?

Comment: Thank you Ninja - your screenshots were extremely helpful. Notice that the label is used in the drill down, while the API name is used for the actual field. I was searching using the label (which was changed and doesn't match the api name), which is why I wasn't seeing it. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: No Problem. Glad you got it working.